# Issue with Image movement on mousemove (in opposite direction)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, mousemove, onmousemove

I have to move an image using jQuery / Javascript exactly like this [url](http://chaikenclothing.com/#/collections/attachment/11/)

I have done [similar to this](http://jsfiddle.net/N2k6M/1/) using my own logic. But it gets cut for smaller / bigger image either at the top or at the bottom. Or It moves completely at the bottom and doesn't move completely at the top or vice-versa.

http://jsfiddle.net/N2k6M/
(Please move the horizontal scrollbar to view full image.)

Can anyone please suggest me  / Fix my code here, so that my mousemove functionality works perfectly fine and upper / lower part of image moves properly.

I need a seamless movement of image just like in the original url.

**HTML PART**

```
<div id="oheight" style="z-index:1000;position:absolute;">123</div> , <div id="yheight" style="z-index:1000;position:absolute;">123</div>

    <img id="avatar" src="http://chaikenclothing.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/11.jpg![enter image description here][2]" style="position:absolute;overflow:hidden;" />
```

**JAVASCRIPT PART**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
<script lang="javascript">
var doc_height = $(document).height();
function updateAvatarPosition( e )
{
    var avatar = document.getElementById("avatar");
    var yheight = parseInt(e.y);
    var ywidth = e.x;
    //avatar.style.left = e.x + "px";
    
    
    if((yheight)<(doc_height)){     
        yheight*=2;
        avatar.style.top = '-'+(yheight) + "px";
    }
    console.log(yheight);
    $("#oheight").html(doc_height);
    $("#yheight").html(yheight);
    /*if((ywidth)<(doc_height/6)){
        avatar.style.top = '-'+e.x + "px";
    }*/ 
}

document.getElementById("avatar").onmousemove = updateAvatarPosition;


</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see http://jsfiddle.net/N2k6M/7/

```
function updateAvatarPosition( e )
{
    var img_height = $('#avatar').height();
    var window_height = $(window).height();
    var factor = (img_height - window_height) / window_height;
    if(factor > 1) {
        var avatar = document.getElementById("avatar");
        var yheight = parseInt(e.clientY);
        avatar.style.top = '-'+(yheight * factor) + "px";    
    }
}
```

Comment: hey thanks dude! This code works fine. The design file where I am working makes me work on margin-top rather than top. In that case the top / margin-top will reach 0px at some point. Because of which the top portion of the image on small browsers < (1024*768) appears to have gone cut. Is there any work around for this.

Comment: Hi! I got solution for my problem. 

The image we use to get the effect should always be higher than the browser window. No matter what the browser height is. This will solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

@Felix's answer is great and works well, however it's doing more work than necessary. There are a few constants that do not need to be reassigned with every call. By setting these outside of the updateAvatarPosition function you can improve performance some.

```
var avatar = $('#avatar');
    img_height = avatar.height(),
    window_height = $(window).height();

function updateAvatarPosition( e )
{
    var factor = (img_height - window_height) / window_height,
        yheight = parseInt(e.clientY);

    if (factor < 1) {
        factor = 1;
    }

    avatar.css('top', -(yheight * factor));
}

avatar.on('mousemove', updateAvatarPosition);
```

​
[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N2k6M/10/)

Avatar is referenced more than once so no need to traverse the DOM multiple times, especially multiple times within a constantly cycling event like mousemove. Make a variable reference to avatar outside of the function. The image_height and window_height are also constants and do not change, so there is no need to recalculate them every time as well. If there is the chance that they would change, reassignment should be handled by a resize event.

Would have replied/commented directly under @Felix's answer but apparently don't have enough influence yet. :-/

Answer (score 0):

i think this is something you want
http://jsfiddle.net/N2k6M/6/

```
var doc_height = $(document).height();
function updateAvatarPosition( e )
{
    var avatar = document.getElementById("avatar");
    var yheight = parseInt(e.clientY);
    var ywidth = e.clientX;

    if((yheight)<(doc_height)){        
        yheight*=2;
        avatar.style.top = '-'+(yheight) + "px";
    }
    /*if((ywidth)<(doc_height/6)){
        avatar.style.top = '-'+e.x + "px";
    }*/    
}

document.getElementById("avatar").onmousemove = updateAvatarPosition;​
```

Comment: Your answer is not solving my problem. I can see that you have changed y to ClientY. But it is getting cut at the top. I need a seemless movement both at the top and at the bottom, like the original url. http://chaikenclothing.com/#/collections/attachment/11/

Comment: what does you mean by cut at the top?

Comment: Please check the url:  http://jsfiddle.net/N2k6M/6/ and this image. http://i.stack.imgur.com/7OlEw.png. When you scroll completely at the bottom complete image doesnt move upwards. It gets cut. In the original url http://chaikenclothing.com/#/collections/attachment/11/ it works fine.